# Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME]..com.amazon.kindle.otter.oobe/.OobeHomeActivity

Tags: android-permissions

This is a very rare error on an Amazon device.
Code:

```
        Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(startMain);
```

This code usually works flawlessly on all kinds of devices. We have seen the following exception on an Amazon device:

```
Class: java.lang.SecurityException
 Stack trace: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.amazon.kindle.otter.oobe/.OobeHomeActivity } from ProcessRecord{ac36ce9 12414:net.my.app/u0a218} (pid=12414, uid=10218) requires android.permission.MANAGE_USERS
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1951)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1919)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1869)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityManager.java:3755)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1669)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4617)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:780)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4575)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:761)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4936)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4904)
```

The exception message gives a good hint: "requires android.permission.MANAGE_USERS"

Could anyone shed some light on this requirement? Why do other devices not require this? Is this device specific or related to a certain configuration by the user?